# Open activity by datepick Android

Tags: android

It is possible to open an activity by datepick?
eg: i mean the date come from DB and the activity will be only avaible when the date is correct 12/10 will not opne 12/12  now the user can access the activity.

Comment: Provide some code and what have you done ?

Comment: hi, im justs asking if it is possible or not and how i can do it logically

Comment: Yes it is possible. But what you want to say about this activity will only open 31/1/17 ?

Comment: yes only that day for example

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with OnDateChangedListener
e.g.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
datePicker.init(calendar.get(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,OtherActivity.class));

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. Not sure what your plan is exactly, so here's some pseudocode on how you might implement that:

```
pickDateListener
    Intent for DateActivity
    add extra to intent(picked date)
    startActivity(intent)
```

And then on the DateActivity:

```
getIntent.getExtras("date")
```

With the date that you get from the extras you can do whatever you want to do for that specific date!

Comment: i want when a user  register select a date  to open a specific activity for example: let say the user its go to have a surgery and  the info about the surgery will be only possible to open the date he choosed

Comment: I would recommend only using one activity, and using the date picked to dynamically change the content of views in that activity. An efficient way to do that would be to have a database (SQLite or Firebase, for example) and save info about the surgery under that date. That way, you could ask the database for all info on that day, and change views accordingly. I would recommend you to find some info or tutorials on how to dynamically add content to an activity.